# KIVY: Can I have a scrollview inside of a scrollview?

Tags: python, kivy

As the title suggests, I want to have a scrollview inside of a scrollview. I tried the following, but the second scrollview doesn't appear at all:

```
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    
    KV = '''
    <MyTile@SmartTileWithStar>
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "240dp"
    
    
    ScrollView:
    
        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
            spacing: dp(4)
    
            MyTile:
                stars: 5
                source: "cat-1.jpg"
    
            MyTile:
                stars: 5
                source: "cat-2.jpg"
    
            MyTile:
                stars: 5
                source: "cat-3.jpg"
                
                
                
                
            ScrollView:
            
                MDGridLayout:
                    cols: 3
                    adaptive_height: True
                    padding: dp(4), dp(4)
                    spacing: dp(4)
            
                    MyTile:
                        stars: 5
                        source: "cat-1.jpg"
            
                    MyTile:
                        stars: 5
                        source: "cat-2.jpg"
            
                    MyTile:
                        stars: 5
                        source: "cat-3.jpg"
    '''
    
    
    class MyApp(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
    
    MyApp().run()
```

Is this not allowed or something? Because the current scrollview is inside a RecycleView and it works fine.

Comment: Not sure what is going on there, but if you remove `adaptive_height: True` from the enclosing `MDGridLayout`, I think the inside one will show up

Comment: That's true, it does show up, but then the parent scrollview stops scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this same question many times on SO, but didn't recognize it at first. The problem is that the `adaptive_height: True` means that the `MDGridLayout` queries its children for their height, and uses that to calculate the minimum height. In your case, the inner `ScrollView` has the default values of `size_hint` (which is `(1,1)`). Whenever you use `adaptive_height` (or `height: self.minimum_height`), you must ensure that the children have well defined heights. Since the inner `ScrollView` does not have a well defined height, the `MDGridLayout` assigns it a height of zero. Here is a snippet of your `kv` with one possible fix:

```
    ScrollView:    # this is the inner ScrollView
        size_hint_y: None
        height: inner_grid.height
        MDGridLayout:
            id: inner_grid
            cols: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4)
            spacing: dp(4)
```

This specifies the `height` of the inner `ScollView` as the `height` of the inner `MDGridLayout`.